# Is the emergence of a new quotative a syntactic innovation?

Tags: syntax, language-change

I am not sure on what level the emergence of a new quotative is classified. Is it syntax?

My question concerns a variety of English. There are several quotatives commonly used in English, such as *„say“*, *„be like“* etc. and also new quotatives emerge over time. In this variety a new quotative form has emerged, and I‘m not sure on what level (lexis, syntax?) of language change this can be classified.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica a [quotative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotative) is a part of speech in some language. I'd assume that's what is meant. I'm still not sure I understand the rest of the question.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise enough and thank you for your input. I have updated my question, I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly **grammaticalisation** in action. Back in [1991](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/423/ling.wp.v16.n1.paper3.pdf?sequence=1) it was already being portrayed as such, and seems to originated in being extended from its meaning of *approximately*. Hence the development of quotative *like* in English, like grammaticalisation in general is all about the interface between semantics and syntax.

Whether this can be considered a complete innovation depends on your perspective and definitions, but I think it's definitely worthy of being portrayed as such. The last time that English had such a quotative was, arguably, with the defective verb [*quoth*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quoth).

A note about terminology: this English "quotative" *like* does not correspond very closely to its grammatical use in e.g. Korean, where "reportive" 애/대 *ae/-dae* is [distinguished](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/be14/e7de905af0fed6bd54b71425b4aa255cb5a0.pdf) from the true "quotative" ~고 *-go*, and English "quotative" *like* is probably closer to the "reportive".

Just to compare diachronic processes: for Korean, the quotative ~고 *-go* [derives](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=zxOsCAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA184) from the ["conjunctive" suffix](http://ira.lib.polyu.edu.hk/bitstream/10397/5147/1/Leidenppt-finalrevision-2012.pdf) meaning "and", whereas ~애 came directly one of the plain (non-formal non-polite non-honorific) forms of 하다 *hada* meaning "to do, make, say".